# Isotrivial K3 family and Picard number

Tags: k3-surfaces, complex-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Is it true that any family of K3 surfaces over $\mathbb{C}$ whose Picard number is constant is isotrivial? Here isotrivial means locally analytically trivial.

Speculation: Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the moduli space of K3 surfaces over $\mathbb{C}$. It is known that for any point $[S]\in \mathcal{M}$ its open neighborhood $U$ contains a K3 surface $[T]$ such that $Pic(S)>Pic(T)$ and such points are dense. So basically I am asking whether I can take a family avoiding these points or not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can take arbitrary family and remove the points where the Picard number jumps.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is yes. This is proven in a paper by Oguiso.

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011258

There is a slightly more general criterion for the density of Hodge loci which appears for instance in this survey of Voisin (section 3.2)

http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~voisin/Articlesweb/hodgeloci.pdf

and is attributed to Mark Green.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question is yes:

http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9701013

**Edit:** As Sasha points out, this is only for compact families.

Comment: Isn't it about compact families only? 

Comment: Sorry, yes I was assuming that was what was wanted!

Comment: The result holds more generally even if the base isn't compact; by a result of green, the jumping locus is analytically dense so you can't just remove the points.

Comment: Sorry - edited to reflect comments.